# Semidirect product operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working on a problem involving semidirect products and I'm just not understanding the operation involved.

One of the automorphisms of $Z_8$ maps $x$ to $x^3$. The homomorphism of $Z_2$ into this automorphism is $\theta: y ->[x->x^3]$. Denote the semidirect product associated with this automorphism, G.

Let (h,k) be an element of G.

Can someone please explain to me why when k is not the identity that (h[$\theta (k)](h),k^2$) = (h$h^3$, $k^2$).  I don't understand why $[\theta (k)](h)=h^3$.

Am I correct in saying that $[\theta (k)](h)=khk^{-1}$? That's what I thought the definition for the operation was. But how does that equal $h^3$?

And what about when k is the identity element? What is $[\theta (k)](h)$ equal to?

Comment: Your notation is extremely confusing.  In fact, I think if you switched notation things would be clear enough to obviate the need to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

The semi direct product tells you how to multiply $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. If we had a direct product $X\times Y$, we would just set
$$
(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2) = (x_1y_1,x_2y_2).
$$
By removing the parentheses, and thinking of the $X$ and $Y$ as subgroups of some larger group that intersect only in the identity, we can imagine that we're really just specifying how $Y$ conjugates $X$:
$$
x_1y_1x_2y_2 = x_1(y_1x_2y_1^{-1})y_1y_2.
$$
For a semi direct product, we therefore need $X$ to be normal, and we can think of the conjugation of $Y$ acting on $X$ as specifying a homomorphism $Y\to Aut(X)$. For example, in the direct product case, we would get $y_1x_2y_1^{-1} = x_2$, so the map above sends every element of $Y$ to the identity.

In your case, you're looking at the semi direct product $\mathbb Z_8 \rtimes \mathbb Z_2$, so we need to specify a homomorphism $\mathbb Z_2 \to Aut(\mathbb Z_8)$. Since $0\in \mathbb Z_2$ is the identity, the corresponding automorphism of $\mathbb Z_8$ must be the identity map. For the unique nontrivial element $y\in \mathbb Z_2$, you have specified the map $y(x) = x^3$. Thus, we can intuitively (note this is only intuition) think of this as $y$ conjugating $x$ by $yxy^{-1} = x^3$. Written in the proper form,
$$
(x_1,y)(x_2,y) = (x_1x_2^3,y^2) = (x_1x_2^3,0).
$$